# Mocking Shiro's static method in SecurityUtils with PowerMock

Tags: java, unit-testing, easymock, powermock, shiro

Hi everyone I am trying to mock static method from Shiro package

```
    org.apache.shiro.mgt.SecurityManager securityManager = EasyMock.createNiceMock(org.apache.shiro.mgt.SecurityManager.class);

    SecurityUtils.setSecurityManager(securityManager);

    PowerMock.mockStatic(SecurityUtils.class);

    EasyMock.expect(SecurityUtils.getSubject()).andReturn(null);
    PowerMock.replayAll(SecurityUtils.class);
    PowerMock.verify(SecurityUtils.class);

    Subject s = SecurityUtils.getSubject(); // this call returns null
    s = SecurityUtils.getSubject(); // this call fails with exception below
```

So the idea is that when in my code I have a call to getSubject I return null (I might change this to actual object but for now this would work.

The current issue is that I get exception

```
Usage is: expect(a.foo()).andXXX()
    at org.easymock.internal.MockInvocationHandler.invoke(MockInvocationHandler.java:42)
    at org.easymock.internal.ObjectMethodsFilter.invoke(ObjectMethodsFilter.java:94)
    at $Proxy10.createSubject(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.Subject$Builder.buildSubject(Subject.java:846)
    at org.apache.shiro.SecurityUtils.getSubject(SecurityUtils.java:56)
    at com.mypackage.services.logic.AbstractHibernateTest.abstractBefore(AbstractHibernateTest.java:94)
null
```

Reading up on this the soluation should be the reply method but it doesnt work. Has anyone seen this before, or does anyone have any suggestion how to mock static method in Shiro SecurityUtils?

Cheers

Comment: Is the problem not that you've expected the call once, but then called it twice? Try adding `.times(2)` onto the end of the expectation for `getSubject()`

Comment: adding that doesnt really do anything for me. I have 2 calls here in order to trigger the exception, as it works for the first time but not the second

Answer (score 1):

This solved my issue

```
    SecurityUtils.setSecurityManager(EasyMock.createNiceMock(org.apache.shiro.mgt.SecurityManager.class));

    mockSubject = Mockito.mock(Subject.class);
    threadState = new SubjectThreadState(mockSubject);
    threadState.bind();
```